# Null value issues in my text file

Tags: arrays, text, coldfusion, null, coldfusion-2016

I have a text file with list of values in tab delimited format. A few values are NULL and the file looks like (attached).
After the text file is uploaded I use ColdFusion 2016 to read the file but when I output their values in an array their value shows as NULLs instead of blank elements. 
I use the following to create the array:

```
 <CFSET Arr_detail = "#ListToArray(i,chr(9),true)#">
 Arr_detail: <cfdump var="#Arr_detail#">
```

When I `<cfdump>` the item this way: `Len(Trim(item)` I get 4 instead of 0 (see the bottom screen shot)
Can anyone help me understand how to handle this problem?

`<cfif Len(Trim(item)) NEQ 0>` does not work because the NULL seems to be a string value or 'NULL' but I don't know where this string is coming from?

[image]

Comment: (Update) Though visually it *looks* like 2 tab chars in a row, the NULL result suggests the file actually contains different white space characters. Dump each of the 4 characters in `init_date` and see what the ascii values are. May not be a tab... `<cfloop from="1" to="#len(init_date)#" index="x"><cfset writeDump("#x# = #asc(mid(init_date, x, 1))#")> </cfloop>`

Comment: With ListtoArray(), I also would have expected to see [empty string] instead of NULL. There is an isNull() function in CF - you could see if that properly identifies the NULL values.  In your example, "i" contains the row, but we don't see how the row was created.  If you dump "i", do you see the word NULL anywhere?